# Как из строки String вытащить два значения в две переменные?

Tags: регулярные-выражения, scala

Есть строка String `(User(2,Alex Mcqueen,26,None),99)`.
Мне нужно достать из нее "2" и "Alex Mcqueen" и присвоить эти значения переменным.

```
val id: Int = 2
val name: String = "Alex Mcqueen"
```

как это сделать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например так:

```
val s = """(User(2,Alex Mcqueen,26,None),99)"""
val regex = """User\((\d+),([^,]+)""".r.unanchored
val List(id,name) = s match {
  case regex(i,n) => List(i,n)
  case _ => List("","")
}
println(s"ID: ${id}\nName: ${name}")
```

Результат:

```
ID: 2
Name: Alex Mcqueen
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://rextester.com/RHIBW14017).

**Внимание**: `.unanchored` необходим для поиска частичного совпадения, а не целой строки.

**Подробности регулярного выражения**

- `User\(` - подстрока `User(`
- `(\d+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №1: одна и более цифр
- `,` - запятая
- `([^,]+)` - Захватывающая подмаска №2: один и более символов, отличных от запятой.